# use always same foreach to call different methods with different number of parameters

Tags: php, design-patterns

I have two methods that iterage over the same structure, 
first searching for "div" tags and after searching for "tr" tags. They use the same foreach.

```
public function findClass($nome){
    foreach ($this->conteudo->getElementsByTagName($this->class) as $node) {
        if (preg_match("/" . $nome . "/", $node->getAttribute("class"))) {
            return $node;
        }
    }
}

public function separar($name, $tag){
    foreach ($this->conteudo->getElementsByTagName($this->class) as $node) {
        $aux = array_map($name, explode($tag, $node->textContent));
    }
    return $aux;
}
```

How make a method call the foreach and the next function with different number of parameters.

I try something like this but have problems in the number of parameters

```
public function findClass($nome)
{
    return $this->buscar('classe', $nome);
}

public function applyFuncToExplode($function, $tag){
    return $this->buscar('map', $function, $tag);
}

public function buscar($metodo, [$parameters]){
    foreach ($this->conteudo->getElementsByTagName($this->class) as $node) {
        $this->$metodo($node, [$parameters]);
    }
    $this->class = null;
}

public function classe($node, $nome){
    if (preg_match("/" . $nome . "/", $node->getAttribute("class"))) {
        return $node;
    }
}

public function map($node, $function, $tag){
    return array_map($function, explode($tag, $node->textContent));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not convinced that what you are doing is a good idea but if we ignore that then you can use the call_user_func routine to call a function and pass in the array of paramters:

```
call_user_func_array ( callable $callback , array $param_arr )
```

see:

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out quite what you are trying to do from your post so I cannot write you an in-context example

Comment: I want to make a function to all methods that use the same foreach and execute differents logics inside this foreach with different number of parameters

Comment: Then the big question is how do you decide what function to call? Are you traversing XML/HTML here and using some sort of name symmetry to choose your functions? Otherwise I wonder what there is to gain (other than unreadable code) by "re-using" the foreach loop

Comment: Have no gain, expect every time I call the same loop to find a different html class.

Comment: I set this html class in a variable and use the loop function to find all nodes with this html class and execute the logic passed in "method" parameter, but this logic have different number of parameters. I don't know if this is the best approach to handle this.